# How can I add endpoint behaviors to the client service with duplex contracts?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have created a binding which supports duplex communication, but it needs that the endpoint has the SynchonousReceiveBehavior :

> endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new SynchronousReceiveBehavior());

This is really easy to do on the server side. However, I need to use a duplex contract and I don't find how I can specify this behavior to the host part of my client.
Do you have any idea ?